# how to rolling a ball be GetAxis with Hoerizontal and Vertical in Unity5.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm starting with basic and follow Unity official tutorial on Unity website and youtube channel.
I want to rolling a ball on the plane with Axis x,y,z But as below code my ball only transfer to -y it will not move around on the stage it just fall down follow axis Y (-42.83892).

This is code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed;

    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {

        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.1f, moveVertical);
        rb.AddForce(movement*speed);


    }
}
```

This is my option for **Ground**
 [image]

This is Option for **Player** [image: 2]]

Comment: Does your plane have a collider attached?

Comment: Mesh Collider right? i add already

Comment: Please record a video of the behavior, use https://screentogif.codeplex.com/, I have used that [in the past for questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161321/how-to-make-a-projectile-turn-with-a-arc). Create a GIF then upload it to giphy.com and insert it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Ohhhh, I see your problem.

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.1f, moveVertical);
```

You are adding a 0.1 vertical force on your ball every single frame. Don't do that, just keep the middle property to 0 or it will make your ball fly up as it keeps adding more and more force to the ball.

---

You made your ball collider have a "Trigger Collider" this means it does not "hit" other objects and instead will just pass through it. Make sure you ***uncheck*** the "Is Trigger" box on both the player and the play field.

[image]

---

This is what it should look like:

Player:
[image: [enter image description here]

Ground:
[image]

Comment: Do you have IsTrigger unchecked on both `Player` and `Ground`? I have updated my answer with screenshots from my copy of the project.

Comment: @HengSopheak see my update, You also had a error in the code.

Comment: No I keep going with Unchecked Is trigger I know that and checked on Gravity. And this is code Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical); will never work.

Comment: That is exactly how I have it on my machine and it works fine. Please make a GIF or a you tube clip of the incorrect behavior you are seeing, because I don't understand what is going wrong, you are not explaining it clearly enough.

Comment: I've upload to youtube Please check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEEKcv3N6Ys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105211/discussion-between-heng-sopheak-and-scott-chamberlain).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't attached Rigidbody component to your sphere. Add it and uncheck "use gravity" check box.

as Scott mentioned below you have to uncheck "*Is trigger*".By checking both is Trigger an "*use gravity*" causes the problem that you are facing

But in future you need to use it.

So obviously your Inspector have to be look like this

[image]

Better to follow Unity Official tutorial on [Roll a Ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7C7WWxUxPZE)

**EDIT:** You have to UNCHECK *IS TRIGGER* box, and CHECK *USE GRAVITY* box. if you check both it fell down

Comment: I have attach and check and uncheck again and again but it still not work\

Comment: If I uncheck use gravity it will not rolling anymore

Comment: @HengSopheak I know what you are trying, because i tried that tutorial too, you have to UNCHECK IS TRIGGER, and CHECK USE GRAVITY. if you check both it fell down, if you check neither It just run without control

Comment: I have update my question with all the player and ground option I've try hard to do it more than 5 times check and uncheck. but still the same if not fall down it will go up. It not good as tutorial show

Comment: @HengSopheak Its going up when you just check only Is trigger and unchecking Use Gravity

Comment: When I uncheck Is trigger both in ground and player.
and if I unchecked use Gravity it will go up and if I checked it it will fall down if I check and unchecked it just fall down and go up. only like this.
and if I check is trigger it will fall down within y-12934721893

Comment: @HengSopheak You don't need to have check everything.don't check IS TRIGGER, you need to check only USE GRAVITY component in Rigidbody only, That's all. I'm 100% sure that was the problem. Still you haven't mentioned that you did that :)

Comment: OHHHH, i just figured out his problem... it is not the trigger at all (well, it was one of his problems). It is how he is adding force in the update.